# How does one search for parent (with some parent attribute) for a found xpath?

Tags: selenium, xpath

In a table, rows are present with the following hierarchy:

```
//div[@class='table']
    //div[@class='some_row_n']//......some xpath...//<child with text abc>
    //div[@class='some_row_m']//......some xpath...//<child with text xyz>
```

I can reach xpath with

```
//div[@class='table']//div[descendant::text()="abc"]
```

But is there a way using which I could figure out an xpath to the parent row `'some_row_n'` (or `'some_row_m'` depending on the searched text). The issue is that the number of items in the xpath section `.....some xpath...` above is unknown at design time.

**I am trying to achieve this without having to loop over each row to find text.** This could reduce the coding effort extremely.

Comment: `//div[@class='table']//div[descendant::text()="abc"]/..` will direct you the the result parent. I hope I understood your question

Comment: Instead of providing a handcrafted _HTML_ the actual text based _HTML_ would have helped to construct a well researched answer.

Comment: @ShlomiBazel - i don't have to go back to the previous parent - how much higher in heirarchy the parent is i don't know - but i do know the parent's class. Looking into the solution provided by Yong.

Comment: @Newcontributor - can't write proprietary information

Answer (score 1):

```
//div[@class='table']//div[contains(@class, 'some_row')][.//*[text()='abc']]
```

If the child with text abc is a fixed tag name, for example it's `span` tag, you can make above xpath more precise as following:

```
//div[@class='table']//div[contains(@class, 'some_row')][.//span[text()='abc']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is your xpath: `//div[@class='table']//div[descendant::text()="abc"]`, then you can reach out to its parent or find its parent element using 'parent' axes as below:

`<yourXpath>/parent::*`

In your case, it becomes:

```
//div[@class='table']//div[descendant::text()="abc"]/parent::*
```

The above xpath will fetch you `//div[@class='some_row_n']` if row element is the parent of child element 'child with text abc'